# Limit Player Rotation Up and Down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the basic movement and rotation working however I can not work out a way to limit the rotation up and down. I want to make it so that you cant look more than 90° up and down.

Ive tried multiple ways such as using if statments and using clamp.

using UnityEngine;

public class FPSController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float speed = 5f;
public float sensitivity = 2f;
public GameObject Camera;

CharacterController controller;

float moveFB;
float moveLR;

public float rotX;
public float rotY;



void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    moveFB = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    moveLR = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
    rotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;


    transform.Rotate(0, rotX, 0);
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveLR * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, moveFB * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    controller.Move(transform.rotation * movement);
    Camera.transform.Rotate(-rotY, 0, 0);

}
```

}

With this code you will be able to rotate the camera beyond 90 degrees causing it to be upside down etc

Answer (score 0):

"Camera" is a built-in unity class, I would recommend renaming it to "camera".
Try this to clamp the camera's rotation:
(with your other public floats)

```
public float minAngle = -90;
public float maxAngle = 90;
```

(at the end of FixedUpdate)

```
Vector3 temp = camera.transform.localEulerAngles;
camera.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.DeltaAngle(0, temp.x), minAngle, maxAngle), temp.y, temp.z);
```

Edit: changed eulerAngles to localEulerAngles
Edit 2: changed the order of the arguements of Mathf.DeltaAngle

Comment: I dont know if i added it correctly but when I try it the camera sort of twitches when you look all the way to the ground or up at the sky.

Comment: My bad, I think it should have been camera.transform.localEulerAngles (replace both occurrences of Euler angles with this)

Comment: I had already chanegd it to local. The code does prevent you from rotating the camera beond 90 degrees however it sticks there and causes other problems

Comment: Try replacing `temp.x` with `Mathf.DeltaAngle(temp.x, 0)`

Comment: For me it just causes the screen to shake up and down and you can only move the camera left and right

Comment: I think I messed up the order of the arguments for Mathf.DeltaAngle

Comment: I managed to fix it and just posted the code. Thank you so much for the help and for being so patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it here. Not to sure on how it works but it works. Credit to video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5eE1YL1ZJY

using UnityEngine;

public class FPSController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float speed = 5f;
public float sensitivity = 2f;
public GameObject Camera;

CharacterController controller;

float moveFB;
float moveLR;

public float rotX;
public float rotY;

public float minAngle = -90f;
public float maxAngle = 90f;





void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    moveFB = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    moveLR = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
    rotY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
    rotY = Mathf.Clamp(rotY, minAngle, maxAngle);


    transform.Rotate(0, rotX, 0);
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveLR * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, moveFB * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    controller.Move(transform.rotation * movement);
    Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotY, 0, 0);



}
```

}